# Front camera face detect (Android Studio)

Tags: android, audio, camera, face

Well i heard that there is a camera class already on android studio.

What Im trying to do is Im trying to make an app that turns on the camera when pressed on it and its only front camera and then when it detects the face it self it says something like "You look great today!" i want to record my own voice and put it as my own voice.

So if anyone can guide me how to do something like that, that would be amazing! I researched everywhere!

I've downloaded this already made face detect interface. It works but all i really need to do now is add my voice to it.

1. Open the app
2. Waits until face is detected
3. Says "You look good today"

Thats all i really want! Can you give me some advice or atleast give me some steps how to do it?

Im a noob so take it easy when explaining

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the face detection libraries of native android (and not OpenCV or something more complex) and as soon as the app starts, also keeps track of your face.
You can also put an if statement to check if the face is recognized and also if the vocal message has already been playes.

```
if(recognized_faces != 0 && message_already_played == false){
    //play the message
}
```

This is a piece of code (an Activity) which takes all the photograms from the frontal camera and analyze them. Originally the code painted with a canvas on the photograms and shows them sequentially (like it was a video stream) into "miaImmagine2". If you don't want it, just do not show miaImmagine2 and show only the video camera layer. I've erased many parts of code unnecessary to you, so that probably there is a lot of code to be erased or adjusted. But it can be a nice help for you. So here is the code:

```
package mawashi.alex.driveawake;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.ErrorCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AwakeActivity extends Activity {
    SurfaceView mVideoCaptureView;

    Camera mCamera;

    public Bitmap mFaceBitmap;
    public TextView Testo;
    public Bitmap mFace2Bitmap;
    public ImageView miaImmagine2;
    private MediaPlayer player;
    public SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static final int MAX_FACES = 1;
    int mFaceWidth;
    int mFaceHeight;
    int cameraType = 1; // front
    int frame_sec = 1000000;
    byte[] callbackBuffer;
    PreviewCallback cb;
    public FrameLayout preview;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap b;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever=null;
    Bitmap bmFrame = null;
    FaceDetector.Face[] faces;
    Activity activity;
    Context mContext;
    int index_sleep = 0;
    int consec = 0;
    boolean sleep = false;
    public float  scala = 1;
    public int offset = 0;
    int m = 1;
    int Colore = Color.GRAY;
    private MediaPlayer player2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.detection);
        mVideoCaptureView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.Surface);
        miaImmagine2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = mVideoCaptureView.getHolder();
        videoCaptureViewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.you_look_good);
        videoCaptureViewHolder.addCallback(new Callback() {
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            startVideo();
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
        });
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //************BUTTONS***************************************************************



    //ROTATE THE IMAGE OF 90 DEGREES

    protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera mCamera, int angle){
        Method downPolymorphic;
        try{
            downPolymorphic = mCamera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
            if (downPolymorphic != null)
                downPolymorphic.invoke(mCamera, new Object[] { angle });
        }catch (Exception e1){  }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //******************************************************************************************

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        player.pause();
    }

    //**************************************************************************************
    //*******************************STARTVIDEO*********************************************
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void startVideo() {
        SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = null;
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(1);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("CameraTest", "Camera Open filed");
            return;
        }
        mCamera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
            }
        });
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size cs = previewSizes.get(0);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width,cs.height);


        setDisplayOrientation(mCamera, 90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        if (null != mVideoCaptureView)
            videoCaptureViewHolder = mVideoCaptureView.getHolder();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(videoCaptureViewHolder);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        Log.v("CameraTest","Camera PreviewFrameRate = "+mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFrameRate());
        Size previewSize=mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width* (ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            private long timestamp=0;
            public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Size previewSize=camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
                YuvImage yuvImage= new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height),80, baos);
                byte jpgData[]=baos.toByteArray();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpgData, 0, jpgData.length);
                Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bmp2);   
                Paint paint=new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.setRotate(270,bmp.getWidth()/2,bmp.getHeight()/2);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);   
                faces = new FaceDetector.Face[MAX_FACES];
                int mFaceWidth = bmp2.getWidth();
                int mFaceHeight = bmp2.getHeight();
                PointF midPoint = new PointF();      //inizializza Punto di coordinate float
                FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(mFaceWidth, mFaceHeight,MAX_FACES);
                int facesFound = detector.findFaces(bmp2, faces); //bmp

                if(facesFound > 0 && message_started==false){
                    faces[0].getMidPoint(midPoint);
                    float eyeDistance = faces[0].eyesDistance();
                    float confidence = faces[0].confidence();
                    player.start(); //play of "You look good today!"
                    message_started = true;
                }
                miaImmagine2.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
                //+++++++++++++++++++++PARTE FINALE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                try{
                    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("CameraTest", "addCallbackBuffer error");
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }
        });
        try {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            return;
        }

    }
    //*************************************STARTVIDEO_END***************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //*************************************STOPVIDEO********************************************


    private void stopVideo() {
        if(null==mCamera)
            return;
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        mCamera = null;
    }
    //**********************************STOPVIDEO_END********************************************
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //**********************************FINISH***************************************************
    public void finish(){
        stopVideo();
        super.finish();
    };
    //**********************************FINISH_END***********************************************


    }
```

Comment: Can i use something like that maybe? http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/face-detection-for-camera.html

Comment: Yes, it's exactly face detector the one I've already used and it works perfectly. Here is the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html if you test a solution which simply detect your face, then let me know

Comment: Great! Ill try that one, but i already got one i would like to show you and see what you say. You got any networks for me to contact you on? Like Skype? It would be easier

Comment: I think the best way to share me your code it's github. If you have a github account you can use it to share code and projects with the others and to have your repository everywhere present. You can send me the link and I will download and test your code if you want.

Comment: Alright here thats the one i use. Thats just the camera https://codeload.github.com/rajktariya/Android-Camera2-Front-with-Face-Detection/zip/master

Comment: Hey! Haven't heard from you ages. Did you test the app?

Comment: Oh yes, but it doesn't make Face Detection at real time, so I was looking for my code to pass it to you. As soon as I get it I sent it to you if possible

Comment: That is great! Thank you ever so much

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! And where exactly(and how) do i insert the code. Sorry im new

Comment: This code is the code of the activity which implements face detection. In fact you can see the name of my package, the various imports, the declaration of the class name, the various and typical (for each Activity) callbacks methods (onCreate, onPause, onStop, onDestroy). So this IS an Activity class, and not simply a piece of code to insert into an Activity class. Still, the view which belongs to this activity must have some ViewGroup elements that you can see in the onCreate method. What you don't need you simply erase.

Comment: Hey, Alex as i said before "I am a noob" could you tell me how to import that piece of code?